# If all answers are only perspectives, why are some users trying to delete answers they don't like?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, moderation

Two of my answers keep getting deleted by the same set of users. And when I eventually discover they are deleted, I have to request other users and mods to undelete them.

1. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/40561 
   https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/40561/timeline

   > [image]
2. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/38004 
   https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/38004/timeline

   > [image]

If all answers are only perspectives as [this answer](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1785) by a mod (The Destroyer ♦) says:

> This site has users who follow different philosophies, sects and even atheists. **There's nothing like "correctness" of an answer. There are only perspectives.** Users here should quote a reliable source in their answers. **Users are free to agree or disagree with perspective of an answer.**

...then why are some users like the ones listed above hell-bent on deleting answers they don't like? If one doesn't like such answers, they can simply downvote and move on. But in this case these users are not just content with downvoting, they also want to censor these answers.

Ironically, one of the users who voted to delete my answers, [in a separate meta post](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2072/is-down-voting-due-to-personal-bias-only-encouraged), is complaining about some other user needlessly downvoting their answers!

If a user votes to delete an answer simply because they doesn't like the arguments made, references used or conclusions reached, in the answer, is it considered an abuse of moderation privileges? If yes, how to deal with such users?

Also, considering SE doesn't notify users when their answers are deleted how can one protect their answers from such abuse?

Comment: Aren't these old events where the community was not allowing interpretations of modern gurus? I don't think this is the case now, hopefully. What is the intention to dig all these? Maybe we should discuss more on whether to allow or not (which I think we didn't conclude still) but not point fingers.

Comment: My thoughts: There is no abuse. Some things community assumes and act. If we discuss and get to a understanding and even still this is happening then that should be an abuse.  I think we discussed this recently and but didn't come to proper conclusion but as you can see myself and Pandya later undeleted your posts.

Comment: Please update your link for Destroyer's answer.

Answer (score 3):

> Two of my answers keep getting deleted by the same set of users.

I am one of the users who deleted one of your posts twice. I first deleted and then undeleted it. Let me explain:

There were a lot of discussions that happened on meta to alter the [answering guidelines](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/126/93) we follow on this site. Even I was thinking we should not allow answers from [modern gurus](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2003/93) but then after some days, I agreed that we [should allow](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2005/93). That is why this [post's timeline](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/38004/timeline) shows that I deleted this post first and then undeleted it. Because that happened at the same time. In other words, I don't think the existing answering guidelines require any changes. **We all should agree on this and digest this**.

> And when I eventually discover they are deleted, I have to request other users and mods to undelete them.

Strangely, that is how SE works. You can check this [meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231990/196352). I wish there was indeed a notification when post gets deleted/undeleted. For now, maybe we can request mod or the third delete voter to leave a comment, which we can't rely completely as it depends on individuals.

> then why are some users like the ones listed above hell-bent on deleting answers they don't like?

Can you give any recent incidents of such after the date of the [above misunderstanding](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2005/93) clarification? But anyway, this too doesn't have an accepted answer. So, till then we are fine to stick to the original answering guidelines.

> is it considered an abuse of moderation privileges? If yes, how to deal with such users?

I don't think there is an abuse of moderation privileges. As you can see here from the image you provided, It is the mod who undeleted your post. Maybe after getting understanding, or seeing improvement in the post.

[image]

I urge everyone not to point fingers at each other but act as one community. The **abuse** here is the result of such unnecessary debates which is forming groups in the community. Raising such posts is making the situation uglier than before. We are going into endless debates.

Comment: "All answers should be perspectives based on scriptural statements available. They should not be based on the statements of some modern (non-Sanathan) scholars contradicting scriptures." - from [the other answer](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2090). So your "We all should agree on this [Ancient scriptural experts and Modern book experts (or a mix of both). The answers from these two experts should be allowed on this site.] and digest this" is not working.

Comment: @sv. I agree with you but I don't see such issues any time recently. I think all are slowly letting it be there or just downvoting and moving on. Let me know if that is not the case.

Comment: "Let me know if that is not the case." - it is not, check the delete vote on [S K's answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26715). 2 more votes and the answer will be deleted. Same with [one of my answers](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/38004) listed in the question. 2 delete votes already. One more and it will be deleted yet again. Used to just one, another one showed up after this meta post. Users here don't care about site policies. They see a Delete button, they click it. I'm surprised you think the problem is long resolved. But it is not. @Mr_Green

Comment: @sv. Name the people in this post who consistently voting to delete your posts. Ask them to speak up. I did my part, but still, you can put my name. Try to keep your tone to normal and humble for them to share their thoughts but not start yet another debate :).

Comment: @sv. I understand your frustration. But mostly your posts are with rage & sarcasm which are hiding the actual intent of the post. I suggest you edit your post to highlight the reasons. Suggestions: Put only links to timeline (not images), name the users to speak up (if possibly, humbly), Ask a mod to what to do in such cases. Also, include the links which you mentioned above.

Comment: "I did my part, but still, you can put my name." - yes, you changed your views on this but it was too late. I still had to flag the mods to undelete it. Besides, the screenshot shows you as undeleting the answer. So what's the cause for concern? "Ask a mod to what to do in such cases." - [A previous flag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0pIZ.png) to undelete was declined by some mod. So flagging is a hit & miss.

Answer (score 0):

> If all answers are only perspectives, why are some users trying to
> delete answers they don't like?

All answers should be perspectives based on scriptural statements available. They should not be based on the statements of some modern (non-Sanathan) scholars contradicting scriptures.

> This site has users who follow different philosophies, sects and even
> atheists. There's nothing like "correctness" of an answer. There are
> only perspectives. **Users here should quote a reliable source in
> their answers**. Users are free to agree or disagree with perspective
> of an answer. (From Moderator)

The reliable sources are scriptures of Sanathan dharma. If no scripture provide the answer, then the opinions of scholars may be considerable. But, in both the answers, you are using the opinions of scholars, who may be experts in modern science and are not exalted practitioners of Sanathan dharma. And the answers are clearly contradicting the scriptures.

> Ironically, one of the users who voted to delete my answers, in a
> separate meta post, is complaining about some other user needlessly
> downvoting their answers! If a user votes to delete an answer simply
> because they doesn't like the arguments made, references used or
> conclusions reached, in the answer, is it considered an abuse of
> moderation privileges?

I did not vote to delete the answer just because of the reason that I didn't like the argument. The key reason is that both answers, as I think, are deserved to get deletion since they are misleading the site, using the site to insult scriptures, using the pressure points to push towards wrong zone etc., I did not vote to deletion directly and I had discussion in comments and also had [discussion](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1905/how-to-deal-with-answers-that-are-against-scriptures-or-scriptural-statements-ba) in meta at those times. So, it is not an abuse of a privilige. I discussed with the OP as well as the community. One can observe in the [comments](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/33657/how-knowledge-of-weapons-shastra-%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0-got-lost/40561#comment127360_40561) of an answer mentioned.

In the meta question I asked, I clearly told that the down-voter is not even discussing and down-voting many questions. I did not vote for deletion for all the questions I dislike. You can check or ask some one for stats. So, the comparison is not proper.

> If yes, how to deal with such users?

The argument provided is not true, but I can tell the way to deal with such users. The best way to deal with such users who delete answers for site well being and progress is to answer the questions in our main site with the intention of site progress and need to answer the questions from scriptures only, if available with any kind of perspective one is comfortable with.

Comment: Which is the answer having these lines? "This site has users who follow different philosophies, sects and even atheists. There's nothing like "correctness" of an answer."

Comment: @Rickross Don't know, he attached different link.

Comment: Okay .. BTW there are 100s of answers that I don't like. But I have not cast my delete votes on any one of them. Both those two answers are overwhelmingly rejected by the community itself. And, I personally find them offensive to be even existing specially because of the nature of the sources used. We don't care about those opinions here on this platform. May be valid on Sceptics.SE but certainly not here.

Comment: The question is giving the impression as if some users attempt deleting every answer they don't like. But that is not the case. Those two answers are offensive in my view.

Comment: Yeah, @Rickross I missed that point.

Comment: Hoping that elections will happen soon... Else, some users disturb @Rickross

Comment: I don't think that only having more Mods will help in dealing with this situation. We need many of the old/experienced users to become active again. It's only when majority of these users go inactive these sort of problems crop up. You can see that mostly the problem has reached its heights in 2020 when there has been almost no activity from experienced users. Presence of old/avid users help tackling/reducing this type of problem to a great extent. But making them active again is not under our control. I myself have been inactive for many months previously :(

Comment: @Rickross yeah, I do remember. Due to unavailability of users like you, many users with malice intentions crept in.

Comment: "reliable sources are scriptures of Sanatana Dharma...need to answer the questions from scriptures only" This is an SE Q&A site about Hinduism. This is not a Hindu site. This site has no goal other than answering Q's using references.

Comment: Users/Community decides what references are valid. Scholarly references were allowed since the inception of the site. Refer to [this FAQ](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/126). Users are free to choose the scholars they want to cite. There are no "good" and "bad" scholars. Every scholar and every reference is equally valid on this site. Nationality of a scholar, whether they are Hindu or not does not matter. If you don't like a particular scholar or reference, downvote and move on. This is how answers on any SE site work, this site is no different.

Comment: **In the absence of any scriptural reference**, written works of scholars, researchers and popular personalities can be used which must be providing a relevant answer.

Comment: "In the absence of any scriptural reference" - those are just guidelines, not rules, as [this answer](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1785) says: "Moreover, they are guidelines, not rules." Besides, if someone finds a scriptural reference for a particular question 5 years later, all answers (that came before it) that cite scholarly opinions should be deleted according to you? At this rate a lot of answers citing Vivekananda, Ramakrishna, or a modern scholar/practitioner should be deleted too whenever someone finds a scriptural reference for the same topic.

Comment: @sv. If they are not the practitioners of or against sanathan dharma , yes....But all the people you told are practitioners right....... Because they are just random opinions, not answers.......